# Visual Basic 2010: How to start Windows 7 Sound Application on Recording Tab

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, process.start

I am trying to get MasterPeakValue of any connected, active microphone in Visual-Basic 2010. Using the Naudio framework I can do so for the default audio device, but for non default devices, the Windows (7) Sound App on Recording Tab has to be opened. Therefore, I am searching for a way to Open this App on this exact Tab from Visual Basic code.

Comment: _I am trying to get MasterPeakValue of any connected, active microphone in Visual-Basic 2010_  : **IMMDeviceEnumerator.EnumAudioEndpoints** enumerates all connected microphones (then **IAudioEndpointVolume** to get the  volume)

Comment: Thx, using your answer, I fixed the problem described above by starting to listen to the selected device first and then get the volume.